# PHP: Variable scope in OOP?

Tags: php, oop, scope

Here's my code:

```
class Manual extends controller {

    function Manual(){
        parent::Controller();
     $myVar = 'blablabla';


    }

    function doStuff(){
        echo $myVar; // Doesn't work.
    }

}
```

I've tried various methods to make it work, but I've can't get my head around it. What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Small tip (if this is PHP5): instead of `function Manual` use `function __construct` and instead of `parent::Controller()` use `parent::__construct()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your code, `$myVar` is local to each method.

Perhaps you meant `$this->myVar?`

Comment: Yup: `$this->` when in an object context, `self::` when in a static context.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the $this 'pointer'.

e.g.:

```
class Test
{
     protected $var;

     public function __construct()
     {
          $this->var = 'foobar';
     }

     public function getVar()
     {
          return $this->var;
     }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

```
class Manual extends controller {

   private $myVar;

    function Manual(){
        parent::Controller();
        $this->$myVar = 'blablabla';
     }

    function doStuff(){
        echo $this->$myVar; 
    }
}
```

Even more OOP-like with Setters/Getters

```
class Manual extends controller {

   private $myVar;

    function Manual(){
        parent::Controller();
        setMyVar('blablabla');
    }

    function doStuff(){
        echo getMyVar();
    }

    function getMyVar() {
        return $this->myVar;
    }

   function setMyVar($var) {
       $this->myVar = $var;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function doStuff(){
    echo $this->myVar; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `$myVar` should be ***property of a class***, and you can not do:

```
echo $myVar;
```

You should do:

```
$this->myVar;
```

Answer (score 1):

As written, $myVar is local to both methods.

You need to declare $myVar as a property in the class body

```
protected $myVar;
```

and then use the pseudo variable $this to access the property in methods, including the constructor

```
$this->myVar;
```

Answer (score 1):

`$myVar` field must be declarated as `public/protected` in the parent class or declarated in the descedent class, and in yours `doStuff()` method you must write `$this->myVar` not the `$myVar`